# Visual Studio 2010 insists on inserting spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, formatting, intellisense

Visual Studio 2010 inserts a space between the keyword "function" and the following parenthesis.  Is it possible to turn this off? i.e.

Visual Studio formats my code like:

```
var vsfn = function () { };
```

I would like this formatting:

```
var myfn = function() {};
```

Comment: I would recommend you not to change that behaviour. Many JavaScript programmers consider this as good style in order to express that the function is not being called in this line. So functioncall() would have no space, but eg. if (...) or function foo () {} would have a space.

Comment: Interesting... Crockford recommends the space http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html but on the other hand, it is not used in jQuery's source: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js Is this an epic battle of JavaScript convention?

Comment: Additionally, Crockford specifically recommends it for anonymous functions, and not named functions.

Comment: Also, doesn't the keyword "function" indicate that the function is being declared and not called?  Any JavaScript programmer should be intimately familiar with the function keyword.

Comment: Have to say I agree w/@Lance Fisher and Crockford the most here... Think of it as reminding you that the function has no name. I.e., sticking w/Crockford on this, there is simply always a space after `function` (anonymous or not) and with anonymous all you do is take away the name (not the space) `function () {` vs `function myFunc() {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2010 sp1 introduced a new option: Insert space after function keyword for anonymous functions in
Tools > Options > Text Editor > JScript > Formatting > Spacing .  You can turn it off to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should find these settings here:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > JScript > Formatting > Spacing

Comment: I've tried disabling all of those settings in spacing, but Visual Studio still puts a space between "function" and "()".  I think the only way to solve it at this point, is to disable formatting altogether.