# Visual Studio.NET 2010 javascript formatting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, formatting

In Visual Studio.NET 2010 the editor keeps inserting a space between the function keyword and the parameter set like this:

```
function (event, ui)
```

I can't find anyway to turn it off with out disabling javascript formatting entirely, most of which I like.  While I am sure some folk like this convention, I do not.

I also have Resharper 5.1.3000.12 installed, but it seems unlikely as Resharper doesn't support javascript yet.

If anyway has any thoughts on how to fix this I would appreciate it.

Cheers,
Matthew

Comment: Maybe this is out of line, but... why are you using Visual Studio 2010 as a javascript IDE?

Comment: @jon: It's pretty good at it.

Comment: It has gotten pretty good at it at this point.  I have used others like Aptana for years, but as VS has gotten better there is a small convenience to using the same editor I use for the rest of my project.  That said I may try Aptana again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716095/visual-studio-2010-insists-on-inserting-spaces-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you like it? Is it aesthetics while programming or for better performance in production? If your reason is performance I'd let the IDE do whatever it wants while developing and then run an obfuscator that will compress the code. I use [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

**EDIT #1**

Since you've mentioned it's aesthetics, you can go to Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting. and turn off all the automatic formating and spacing.

example:
[image]

Comment: No it is aesthetics, and I find it irksome that IDE is going to insist upon a particular formatting opinion without allowing to to be turned off.

Comment: As I mentioned above I am clear I can go the nuclear option and shut it all off, but I like most of what it does.  Was hoping that there was something short of that.  Next version of Resharper has javascript support so perhaps they will fix this.

Comment: @Matthew: ohh, well you can shut some things of try only shutting off the "Insert space before and after binary operators"

Comment: Thanks for this, the auto-formatting was really starting to get on my nerves.  I've taken the nuclear option and shut it all off, now instead of "type, undo, backspace, fix, continue" I can just type and go :)

Comment: This will have no effect if you're using the new version of ReSharper. Instead, scroll past `TextEditor` to `ReSharper`, then press `Options`. JavaScript formatting is under the `Code Editing` section.

Answer (score 7):

Open Options, then go to Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting. Uncheck "Insert space after function keyword for anonymous functions":

[image]

Comment: Interesting...your screen looks different than the one that capdragon shows above and I didn't find it earlier, but now I look and it is there. It must have been added in some subsequent release.

Comment: This needs to become the actual answer for this question. THANK YOU.